# PostgreSQL stynax error creating function

Tags: sql, function, postgresql

I am creating a function in my PostgreSQL but I'm getting this syntax error and I ran out of ideas what could be wrong... Please assist.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_docName(IN p_docId_id bigint) 
RETURNS TABLE(name varchar) AS
$BODY$

begin
RETURN query SELECT name * FROM (documents) where id=p_docId
end;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE sql STABLE;
ALTER FUNCTION public.get_documents(IN bigint)
  OWNER TO postgres;
```

Errors:

```
ERROR:  SyntaxError at „RETURN“
LINE 8: RETURN query SELECT * FROM (
        ^
********** Error **********

ERROR: SyntaxError at „RETURN“
SQL state: 42601
Character: 173
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to use PL/PgSQL syntax in an SQL function. You also forgot the semicolon on the end of the `SELECT`.

Declare it `LANGUAGE plpgsql`. Or, as the function is so trivial, just turn it into valid sql function syntax by replacing the body with:

```
$BODY$
SELECT name * FROM (documents) where id=p_docId;
$BODY$
```

though the SQL statement its self is also invalid - `name *`?

Comment: @Jacob That's because that SQL is invalid. What are you trying to write? `name * FROM ...` makes no sense.