# Postgresql syntax error for if statement in a function

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I am trying to write a function in postgresql and i am getting a syntax error for the **if** statement:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION getallcampuses(IN a character varying, IN b character varying)
  RETURNS TABLE(campusid charactervarying, campusname character varying) AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
if $1 = 'PREK' then
     SELECT * from "SIS_campus";
ELSE
    BEGIN
       IF $2 = 'DAll' then
           SELECT distinct(district_id) || 'ALL' AS CampusID, ' District' AS CampusName

           UNION

           SELECT campus_id, name
           FROM   "SIS_campus"
           WHERE  district_name IS NOT NULL
           order by name;
       Elsif $2 = 'All' then

           SELECT campus_id, name
           FROM   "SIS_campus"
           WHERE  district_name IS NOT NULL
           and isnumeric(name) = 0
           order by name;
        end if;
    END
end if;
END
$BODY$
LANGUAGE sql;
```

Here is the error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "if"
LINE 5: if $1 = 'PREK' then
        ^
```

Comment: You have a typo at `Elsif $2 = 'All' then`

Comment: Thanks for including a complete function body and the exact error message text. That's so rare, and is appreciated. (In future, please put your PostgreSQL version in the text too, though).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function body is PL/PgSQL, but you declared it `LANGUAGE sql`.

Use `LANGUAGE plpgsql` if you're writing PL/PgSQL.

([related prior answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24820702/398670))